# Does `Object.const_get` work with strings? I get a "wrong constant name" Error

Tags: ruby

I have a dynamically generated nested namespace like this:

```
class A
  class B
    class C
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I can access class `C` manually by `A::B::C`, so it exists, so my generator works. However `Object.const_get "A::B::C"` raises a "wrong constant name" error. Can I somehow access it dynamically without cumbersome loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without loops? not sure.

here is my solution to this, but it does loop through your names:

```
class A
  class B
    class C
    end
  end
end

c = "A::B::C".split("::").inject(Object) { |n,c| n.const_get c }
p c

A::B::C
```

[**here you can see it in action**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=does-object-const-get-works-with-strings-i-get-a-wrong-constant-name-error.rb&run=true)

Comment: One can wrap it in a helper method :)